# jQuery Mouseup not firing.. in internet explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, mouseup

this is weird. I've been using this code for months and suddenly it doesn't work with some versions of IE (yes, sadly I HAVE TO code for IE).

```
$(document).on("mouseup", ".flatDiv", function(event) {
            switch (event.button) {
                case 0:
                    window.open(
                      'place.php?id='+$(this).attr('id'),
                      '_blank'
                    );
                    break;
                case 1:
                    window.open(
                      'place.php?id='+$(this).attr('id'),
                      '_blank'
                    );
                    break;
            }
        });
```

The reason for the switch is because I used two different actions.

I've looked the whole document and see no problem, it perfectly works in other browsers.
Any ideas?

Edit 1: The mouseup event doesn't fire, an alert before the switch doesn't show up either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: mention the IE version where it is nor working?

Comment: It's IE 9.0.8112.16421 It doesn't work in Chinese Windows